# W3C validation error: there is no attribute "placeholder"

Tags: html, placeholder, w3c-validation

I am getting the following error from W3C validation:

> Line 326, Column 63: there is no attribute `placeholder`
>
> ```
> … type="text" name="pc" id="postcodefield" placeholder="Vul hier uw Postcode" />
> ```
>
> You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
>
> This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error message for further information.
>
> How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute, (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this attribute. If you received this error when using the  element to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid flash.

Please see the source code:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input type="text" name="pc" id="postcodefield" placeholder="Vul hier uw Postcode" />
    <input type="submit" class="search_button" value="Zoeken" id="searchbutton" />
</form>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Use the HTML5 doctype and make sure the validator is validating your markup as HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's because of your `DOCTYPE`. You're currently using HTML5 markup so you need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```